# PySpark: Parsing JSON files where column names are defined once in the header

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

I am trying to use PySpark to parse JSON files where the column names are defined once in the header. I'm getting stuck trying to zip/combine an array of column names to an array of values.

```
json_example = """{
    "Header":
    {
        "Foo": 'bar',
        "SignalList": [
            {"Name": "id", "Type": "integer"},
            {"Name": "field01", "Type": "float"},
            {"Name": "field02", "Type": "float"}
        ]
    },
    "Payload": [
        {
            "Data": [
                [10001, 2.2, -102.4],
                [10002, 2.3, -102.3],
                [10003, 2.2, -102.4],
                [10004, 2.6, -102.4],
                [10005, 2.5, -102.5]
            ]
        },
        {
            "Data":[
                [10006, 2.4, -102.3],
                [10007, 2.5, -102.5],
                [10008, 2.5, -102.5],
                [10009, 2.6, -102.4]
            ]
        }
    ]
}"""
```

My goal is to get it to the following format:

```
+-------+-------+-------+------+
|    id |field01|field02|   foo|
+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  10001|    2.2| -102.4|   bar|
|  10002|    2.3| -102.3|   bar|
|  10003|    2.2| -102.4|   bar|
|  10004|    2.6| -102.4|   bar|
|  10005|    2.5| -102.5|   bar|
|  10006|    2.4| -102.3|   bar|
|  10007|    2.5| -102.5|   bar|
|  10008|    2.5| -102.5|   bar|
|  10009|    2.6| -102.4|   bar|
+-------+-------+-------+------+
```

So far, I'm loading the column names and data values as arrays:

```
# Read JSON
df = spark.read.option("multiLine","true").json(sc.parallelize([json_example]))
# Copy
df1 = df
# Get column names
df1 = df1.withColumn("colnames", F.col('Header.SignalList.Name'))
# Get data values
df1 = df1.withColumn("values", F.explode('Payload.Data').alias('values'))
df1 = df1.withColumn("values", F.explode('values'))
# Get metadata from Header
df1 = df1.withColumn("Foo", F.col("Header.Foo"))
df1 = df1.select(["foo","colnames", "values"])
df1.show(truncate=False)
```

Which results in this:

```
+---+----------------------+----------------------+
|foo|colnames              |values                |
+---+----------------------+----------------------+
|bar|[id, field01, field02]|[10001.0, 2.2, -102.4]|
|bar|[id, field01, field02]|[10002.0, 2.3, -102.3]|
|bar|[id, field01, field02]|[10003.0, 2.2, -102.4]|
|bar|[id, field01, field02]|[10004.0, 2.6, -102.4]|
|bar|[id, field01, field02]|[10005.0, 2.5, -102.5]|
|bar|[id, field01, field02]|[10006.0, 2.4, -102.3]|
|bar|[id, field01, field02]|[10007.0, 2.5, -102.5]|
|bar|[id, field01, field02]|[10008.0, 2.5, -102.5]|
|bar|[id, field01, field02]|[10009.0, 2.6, -102.4]|
+---+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I'm stuck trying to expand the *i*<sup>th</sup> value in the *values* field to a new column with the *i*<sup>th</sup> value in the *colnames* field as the alias.

FWIW, my actual dataset will have around 100 columns in the array.

Comment: Are you using Azure databricks?

Comment: I'm using Azure Synapse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up collecting all the unique column names and using a UDF to lookup the appropriate value of each column:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

# Define a UDF that will lookup a name in 'colnames' array and 
# return the corresponding value in the 'values' array at the same index
def lookup_by_name(name, colnames, values):
    if name in colnames:
        index = colnames.index(name)
        return values[index]
    else:
        return None
lookup_by_name_udf = F.udf(lookup_by_name, DoubleType())

# Get all unique column names across all rows & arrays in "colnames"
unique_colnames = [r.colnames for r in df1.withColumn("colnames", F.explode(col("colnames"))).select("colnames").distinct().collect()]

# Create each unique column name from the "colnames" arrays
for name in unique_colnames:
    df1 = df1.withColumn(name, lookup_by_name_udf(F.lit(name), col("colnames"), col("values")))

# Drop the array columns
df1 = df1.drop('colnames','values')

# Show
df1.show(truncate=False)
```

Result:

```
+---+-------+-------+-------+
|foo|field02|field01|id     |
+---+-------+-------+-------+
|bar|-102.4 |2.2    |10001.0|
|bar|-102.3 |2.3    |10002.0|
|bar|-102.4 |2.2    |10003.0|
|bar|-102.4 |2.6    |10004.0|
|bar|-102.5 |2.5    |10005.0|
|bar|-102.3 |2.4    |10006.0|
|bar|-102.5 |2.5    |10007.0|
|bar|-102.5 |2.5    |10008.0|
|bar|-102.4 |2.6    |10009.0|
+---+-------+-------+-------+
```